# Comparing text values in sales force when text value is two digits

Tags: apex

I have one text field name plannumber.

i want to compare `Integer.valueof(plannumber__c) > Integer.valueof(plannumber__c)`.
But when its giving wrong results when the textfield value `plannumber__c` is greater then 9.

For example it will make 9>10 and giving true.

Converting field type is not option at salesforce level what other alternative can I have at runtime to let it behave at number so that I can compare values.

```
    List<plan__c> planlist = acc.getSObjects('plans');
                if(planlist != null && planlist .size()>0){
                  recentplan = new plan__c();
                  recentplan.plannumber__c = '0';
                  for(plan__c tempplan : planlist){
                      if(tempplan.plannumber__c!= null && Integer.valueof(tempplan.plannumber__c)>Integer.valueof(tempplan.plannumber__c)){
                          recentplan = tempplan;
                      }
                  }

//process on the basic of tempplan
                  acc.value= recentplan .amount__c;

              }
```

Comment: how are comparing same field value Integer.valueof(plannumber__c)> Integer.valueof(plannumber__c) ? Is that Trigger.old and Trigger.new

Comment: Actually we have one logic to figure out record with highest value for plannumber__c field value, so we do like we initialize temp with zero and start comparing with next and so on. There is Trigger on Plan which run and calcuate on Trigger.new for all records and filter with highest value for plannumber__c

Comment: Can you post your code here

Comment: @DavidMycka This makes no sense as you are comparing the same value and it will never be great as it will always be equal. You are essentially doing '9'>'9'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wrongly comparing the values.

Currently it is: `Integer.valueof(tempplan.plannumber__c)>Integer.valueof(tempplan.plannumber__c)`

You should compare with `tempOpp.plannumber__c` and `tempplan.plannumber__c`. So put the conditions properly.

Example:

```
for(plan__c tempplan : planlist)
{
    if(tempplan.plannumber__c!= null 
        && Integer.valueof(tempOpp.plannumber__c)>Integer.valueof(tempplan.plannumber__c)){
                recentplan = tempplan;
    }
}
```

Now, verify how the conditions to be satisfied to make `recentplan = tempplan;`

Comment: Wouldnot still this compartion will fail when 9>10 will be consider true by salesforce. As for text it is true. plannumber__c is text value at salesforce level

Comment: It will not. @DavidMycka, your problem is that your code is comparing the value to ITSELF. Obviously, a number can never be greater than itself.

Comment: I  just checked, it is working fine only again for 0 to 9. For double digits it is failing. You can check this developer console for any text value in salesforce

Answer (score 2):

While your posted code does not make sense as you are comparing the same value the following should help in the case that your posted code is not actually what you are using

```
String a = '9';
string b = '10';

System.debug(('0' + a).right(2)>('0' + b).right(2)); //WORKS
System.debug(integer.valueOf(a) > integer.valueOf(b)); //WORKS
```

Essentially we are adding a 0 and then taking the right 2 characters to ensure we are always comparing a string containing 2 digits.

BUT, **you do not need to do that** as the second debug outputs correctly as well

This goes back to the initial problem, you are comparing the same values

```
Integer.valueof(tempplan.plannumber__c)>Integer.valueof(tempplan.plannumber__c)
```

will always evaluate to false as the are *equal*

Comment: Thanks Eric for help. Just one more thing, when we take any value text in salesforce it will come as string when we query in apex right?.

Comment: @DavidMycka - If it is a TEXT field then yes. When querying a field in SF it will be returned as the type the field is defined as

Comment: Thanks ERIC. You are awesome. I would give you a best answers but since Santanu gave first, i would give him. But you are awesome :)

Comment: @DavidMycka - Well what was the issue then? You said the other answer did not work?

Comment: i have look into my code now, since i am not getting right results when i running that. I have  updated the code as per suggestion here. But still results are not comming right. But i am satisfied with answers here. I will update group here once i figure out root cause.